# libpulse-dev version does not match libpulse version

Tags: package-management, pulseaudio, dependencies, synaptic

I have been trying to install libsdl1.2-dev and have been running into an issue with one of its dependencies. When I attempt to mark libsdl1.2-dev for installation in Synaptic, fails with the error: "Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed."

By trying to install libpulse-dev manually I have determined that the problem is that the version of libpulse offered is a [more recent version](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/P9_GhMCb2Y92qZWFh3K__g67T-hvdUhd0Icf_MOiOHUARFcL2yYCHAejmlgD34PtOGeSax35sdzzwJ8=w1829-h983) than the version of libpulse-dev offered; apparently someone pushed a newer version of the pulseaudio binaries into the repository without bothering to push the new versions of the header files as well. As a result of this, Synaptic detects the version mismatch between the two packages and refuses to install libpulse-dev.

I have done some research and considered these options:

1: Downgrading my version of libpulse in order to match the version of libpulse-dev.

2: Using apt-get to download libpulse-dev [ignoring its dependencies](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies).

However, neither of these options seem like a good solution to me. Synaptic does not handle downgrades anywhere near as gracefully as it handles upgrades; it wants to uninstall dozens of programs when I mark libpulse for downgrade. I'm also concerned that downgrading libpulse could put me in dependency hell, with other programs also needing to be downgraded to be compatible with the older version of libpulse, although I'm too scared to find out if this is actually the case. The second option also seems dangerous, as presumably some structs and function prototypes may have changed in the new version of pulseaudio. I'd rather not use out-of-date header files unless I know for a fact that there were no interface changes which could lead to subtle, headache-inducing bugs down the road.

So, does anyone know of a safer way to work around this issue? I am still running 12.04LTS for various reasons, if that makes a difference in the situation.

Additional information:

```
 apt-cache policy libsdl1.2-dev
 libsdl1.2-dev:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3.1
   Version table:
      1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3.1 0
         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
      1.2.14-6.4ubuntu3 0
         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages

 apt-cache policy libpulse-dev
 libpulse-dev:
   Installed: (none)
   Candidate: 1:1.1-0ubuntu15
   Version table:
      1:1.1-0ubuntu15 0
         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages


 apt-cache policy libpulse0
 libpulse0:
   Installed: 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4
   Candidate: 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4
   Version table:
  *** 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4 0
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
      1:1.1-0ubuntu15 0
         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libsdl1.2-dev; apt-cache policy  libpulse-dev; apt-cache policy  libpulse` and give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: For simplicity's sake you can go apt-cache policy package name package name package name

Comment: @A.B. Information added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed version `1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4` of `libpulse-dev` is in [precise-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise-updates&searchon=names&keywords=libpulse-dev). The simplest way to activate this repository is:

1. Start <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>
2. Select the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>
3. Select <kbd>Recommended updates (precise-updates)</kbd> (In my screenshot it's vivid-updates, but that's just an example)

   [image]

   And click <kbd>Close</kbd>
4. Click <kbd>Reload</kbd> in this dialog

   [image]
5. Install `libsdl1.2-dev` again